# Mapping Class group of 3-manifold $S^1\times S^1\times D^1$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, mapping-class-group

Is Mapping Class group of  $S^1\times S^1\times D^1$ trivial? $D^1$ stands for 1-dimensional disc. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Far from being trivial, it is an infinite group.

To see this, first you need the theorem from surface theory that the canonical homomorphism
$$\text{MCG}(S^1 \times S^1) \to \text{Aut}(H_1(S^1 \times S^1)) \approx \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2) \approx GL(2,\mathbb{Z})
$$
is an isomorphism.

Next, the projection map $p : (S^1 \times S^1) \times D^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ is a homotopy equivalence, so it induces a homomorphism
$$\text{MCG}((S^1 \times S^1) \times D^1) \to \text{Aut}(H_1(S^1 \times S^1)) \approx GL(2,\mathbb{Z})
$$

Finally, this homomorphism is onto because every homeomorphism $f : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ extends to a homeomorphism
$$f \times \text{Id} : (S^1 \times S^1) \times D^1 \to (S^1 \times S^1) \times D^1
$$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the mapping class group of a torus is $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: This depends on whether you follow the most common convention for defining the mapping class group or an orientable surface, which requires orientation to be preserved. The orientation preserving mapping class group of a torus is indeed $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. But if you allow homeomorphisms that reverse orientation, then you get $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. I broke convention in my answer because it allows for the simplest answer to the OP's question. @SantanaAfton

Comment: Oh, I see -- that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!